# mysqli_fetch_array iteration issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a page that is dynamically generated using PHP and a MySQL database. The page displays information about an event, and lists the dates that event will run.

My database has the following relevant tables:

`events` - containing the event name, cost etc

`venue` - containing venue information

`instance` - containing the event_id, venue_id, the date the event at that venue will run, and the capacity for that instance.

`registration` - containing the instance_id, and attendee_id.

To grab all the information to actually display the event information, I use the following code:

```
$eid = $_GET['event_id'];
        $q = "SELECT e.event_name, e.event_description, e.event_byline, e.event_benefit, e.event_cost, e.event_exam, e.event_resi, i.venue_id, i.instance_id, i.instance_cap, v.venue_name, DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' ) AS DATE
        FROM events AS e
        INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.event_id = i.event_id
        INNER JOIN venue AS v ON i.venue_id = v.venue_id
        WHERE e.event_id = $eid
        ORDER BY i.venue_id, i.instance_date";

        $cur_venue = 0;
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Now, what I want to do is display a list, sorted by venue, of the instances for the relevant event, which I have done up to a point. However, what I also want to do is *only* display the instance if there is space left *on* that particular instance.

Since I know the capacity of each instance (from my `instance_cap` column), and I can `COUNT` the number of attendees registered to each instance, I figure I can do this thuswise:

```
do
{
    $list_instance = $row['instance_id'];

    $qRegs = "SELECT COUNT(delegate_id) AS regs FROM registration
    WHERE registration.instance_id = $list_instance";
    $rRegs = mysqli_query($dbc,$qRegs);
    $registrations = mysqli_fetch_object($rRegs);

    $capacity = $row['instance_cap'];

    $availability = $capacity - $registrations->regs;

    if ($availability > 0){ //if event has places available...
        if ($cur_venue != $row['venue_id']) //and if the current venue is not the same as the venue id
        {
            echo '<li id="'.$row['venue_name'].'">'
            $cur_venue = $row['venue_id']; 
            echo '<h4>'.$row['venue_name'].'</h4>';//display the venue name
        }
        echo '<a href="#">'.$row['DATE'].'</a>' //display the date for current instance
        echo '</li>';//close list tag
    }
} while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC));';
```

The problem I have is that this misses out the first instance and skips straight to the second one. I understand that this is probably due to the fact that I have called `mysqli_fetch_array` twice, so how I can work it so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Should be able to consolidate this into one query and just use the results directly.

Comment: @TiesonT. I can't see how to do this given that there are multiple instances of each event. I am a total noob though :)

Comment: I'll admit that SQL isn't my strong suite, but try running the updated query below in MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin and see if you get the result you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to run one query, and then just use the resultset. Try this:

```
SELECT e.event_name, e.event_description, e.event_byline, 
e.event_benefit, e.event_cost, e.event_exam, e.event_resi, 
i.venue_id, i.instance_id, i.instance_cap, v.venue_name, 
DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' ) AS DATE
FROM events AS e
INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.event_id = i.event_id
INNER JOIN venue AS v ON i.venue_id = v.venue_id
WHERE e.event_id = $eid AND i.instance_cap > (SELECT COUNT(r.delegate_id) FROM registration AS r WHERE r.instance_id = i.instance_id)
ORDER BY i.venue_id, i.instance_date
```

Granted, this is untested, so it might not work as-is.

**EDIT:** a sub-query is probably more correct. See the edited query above.

Comment: This gives an error - 'Unknown column 'regs' in 'where clause'

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Okay, one last try; see the updated query above.

Comment: Will do. To help me understand what's going on here, am I correct in thinking that this should get only instances that have availability (ie less registrations than capacity)? So I don't need to do any checking of availability, I just need to output the results?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Yep. The sub-query should return a count of matching registrations. That value is then compared against the value of `instance_cap` for the "current row". If the evaluation is false the row is excluded from the result set.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall You also will want to look into prepared statements; I didn't notice `$eid` being injected in the query string, which generally a bad idea. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I use prepared statements whenever I'm updating or inserting into the database - I wasn't aware there was an issue in SELECT queries...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Yeah, it wouldn't be too hard to inject SQL to return, say, all your login info, so **every** query should be prepared if it uses "dynamic" values.

Comment: Hmmm - better make that query use a prepared statement then! It works by the way, thanks very much. I like to keep things elegant where I can.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
mysqli_data_seek ( $r , 0 );
```

before the second mysqli_fetch_array to reset the internal pointer to the first instance.

Comment: Or skip the first `$row=` and do a _'while loop'_ instead of a _'do while loop'_

Comment: This didn't work - perhaps I'm putting it in the wrong place? I'm putting it just before the `do`